# Android. How to correct launch coroutine without blocking UI?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, coroutinescope

I'm new in coroutines. And I'm trying add it to my project. Also I'm using MVVM.
In the documentation I read `viewModelScope.launch { }`:

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread

But at the same time, I often see code constructs like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   launch {
      // call some suspend fun here
  }
}
```

Why is another `launch{}` here if the documentation says that `viewModelScope.launch { }` launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread.

Wouldn't it be enough to write like this:

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
    // call some suspend fun here
  }
```

Could such a construction (launch inside viewModelScope.launch) be useful in some cases? Maybe I don't understand something, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  // call some suspend fun here
}
```

is enough to launch a coroutine and execute a suspend function without blocking UI.

The `launch` within `launch` is used to launch tasks in parallel, for example:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   launch {
      // call task 1
      task1()
   }
   launch {
      // call task 2
      task2()
   }
}
```

`task1()` and `task2()` are `suspend` functions and will execute in parallel.

But if we write like the following:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   task1()
   task2()
}
```

`task2()` will wait until `task1()` is completed and then will start execution.